# NSIS Installer error - Not enough memory resources available to process this command

Tags: batch-file, installation, cmd, nsis, silent-installer

I have created an installer using NSIS package to install my own software along with some 3rd party softwares such as Notepad++ and winPython. Batch scripts are being run to install notepad++ and winPython. The winPython which is packaged into the installer is in a zipped format "winPython3940.7z". This is being unzipped into a folder as a part of the installer using the following `.nsh` script.

```
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Install Third Party Software
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Section "Install Third Party Software"
; Execute Notepad++ installer
${If} $Notepad_userDecision == "1"      
    DetailPrint ""
    DetailPrint "----------------- Install Notepad++ -----------------"
    DetailPrint ""

    DetailPrint "Create Notepad++ install batch..."
    ${textreplace::ReplaceInFile} "${TEMP_PATH}installer_template.bat" "${TEMP_PATH}install_notepad.bat" "#INSTALL_CMD" '"${TEMP_PATH}Notepad\npp.7.8.7.Installer.x64.exe" /S' "/S=1 /C=1 /AO=1 /PI=0 /PO=0"  $0
    DetailPrint "Execute Notepad++ install batch..."
    nsExec::Exec "${TEMP_PATH}install_notepad.bat"
${EndIf}

; --------> PROBLEMATIC PART: Execute WinPython installer
${If} $WinPython_userDecision == "1"
    ; Delete old winPython Installation
    DetailPrint ""
    DetailPrint "----------------- Delete old WinPython installation -----------------"
    DetailPrint ""
    
    DetailPrint "Create WinPython uninstall batch..."
    ${textreplace::ReplaceInFile} "${TEMP_PATH}installer_template.bat" "${TEMP_PATH}uninstall_winpython.bat" "#INSTALL_CMD" 'if exist ("${PYTHON_PATH}" rmdir /s /q "${PYTHON_PATH}")' "/S=1 /C=1 /AO=1 /PI=0 /PO=0"  $0
    DetailPrint "Execute WinPython uninstall batch..."
    nsExec::Exec "${TEMP_PATH}uninstall_winpython.bat"
    
    DetailPrint ""
    DetailPrint "----------------- Install WinPython -----------------"
    DetailPrint ""

    DetailPrint "Create WinPython install batch..."
    ${textreplace::ReplaceInFile} "${TEMP_PATH}installer_template.bat" "${TEMP_PATH}install_winPython.bat" "#INSTALL_CMD" 'if exist "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "${TEMP_PATH}WinPython\winPython3940.7z" -o${PYTHON_PATH})' "/S=1 /C=1 /AO=1 /PI=0 /PO=0"  $0
    DetailPrint "Execute WinPython install batch..."
    nsExec::Exec "${TEMP_PATH}install_winPython.bat"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Notepad++ gets installed perfectly (without any popup cmd windows) as well as winPython, but the former has a couple of soft bugs. 2 batch scripts are being run to delete an old winPython installation and then installation the new one. When the installer is running, both of these scripts open up 2 individual cmd windows where the second one opens up after the first one is closed. Scripts get executed perfectly but they both contain "*Not enough memory resources available to process this command*"
[winPython uninstaller script's cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9TOq.png) and [winPython installer script's cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaXho.png).

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: That error is not coming from NSIS. What does the bat file look like?

Comment: @Anders The content is mentioned in the code above on the lines which have ```${textreplace::ReplaceInFile}```. The content starts from #INSTALL_CMD

Comment: what does the rest of the bat contain?

Comment: @Anders ```if exist ("${PYTHON_PATH}" rmdir /s /q "${PYTHON_PATH}")``` is the rest of the content

Comment: Why do you need a bat file then? Just do these operations in NSIS.

Comment: @Anders Is that a possibility? How can I unzip a file silently in NSIS using 7zip or default windows decompression program?

Comment: I meant not using a bat, nsExec 7z.exe directly.

Comment: @Anders Alright thanks! I will try that out. Would if statements like ```if exist ("${PYTHON_PATH}" rmdir /s /q "${PYTHON_PATH}")``` work too? I only ask because it takes very long to create the installer (>20min) due to large softwares being packed into it

Comment: Just experiment in another .nsi file.

Comment: ${PYTHON_PATH} should probably be a $variable, not a ${define} but it is hard to tell without seeing all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is not coming from NSIS, it must be from something inside your batch file, perhaps 7-Zip.

There is no reason to use a batch file to delete something, just use NSIS:

```
Section "Prepare Example"
CreateDirectory "$temp\fakepython\something\somethingelse"
CopyFiles /SILENT /FILESONLY "$WinDir\*.exe" "$temp\fakepython" ; Dummy files
SectionEnd


!include LogicLib.nsh
Var MyDetectedPythonPath

Section
StrCpy $MyDetectedPythonPath "$temp\fakepython" ; Replace this with the correct logic to find Python.

${If} ${FileExists} "$MyDetectedPythonPath\*" ; Probably a good idea to replace * with something like python.exe so you know you found the correct directory
    RMDir /R "$MyDetectedPythonPath"
${EndIf}

DetailPrint "Installing python..."
StrCpy $1 '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /C ping localhost' ; Replace this with your real command
nsExec::Exec '$1'
Pop $0
DetailPrint "Exit code $0"
SectionEnd
```

You could also try [this 7z plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Nsis7z_plug-in) instead of calling 7z-exe.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly! I wasn't aware of this way of deleting things and executing commands. Thanks a lot :D